# How to connect to Google Drive using the Android API and a specific account?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to use Google Drive for cloud sync purposes.

Is it possbile using **Google Drive API** **for Android** to connect to a specific account that will act as a cloud storage server ?

How can I set the user account and password when I try to connect with that specified Google account ?

So far I'm using:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Drive.API)
        .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

But this provides the user with a login dialog to select its own local account which is not what I'm intending to do. Thanks.

Comment: Cant help with android but try googleing Service account

Comment: Yeah, from what I've seen you can't connect to a specific account.

Comment: If you grant the service account access to a folder on your google drive it will have access to that.

Comment: Actually both of those comments are false. You CAN get access to a specific account. See the question I asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230977/using-google-drive-api-parse-to-store-files-on-a-single-drive-account/32276202#32276202 It is a little more specific compared to your question, but it is possible. Let me know if yo need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excerpt from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32288641/how-can-i-create-a-http-rest-request-to-upload-something-to-google-drive/32358099#32358099) answer I gave on a similar question:

There are two main items you need to make a request to a Google API:

1. `refresh_token` - Used to get more `access_tokens` and never expires
2. `access_token` - Used to send API calls (example: upload a file) and expires every 60 minutes.

In order to get either of these you have to follow certain steps.

1. > Obtain a OAuth 2.0 client ID through the Google Developers Console
2. > Obtain an access token from the Google Authorization Server
3. > Send the access token to an API
4. > Refresh the access token, if necessary

More specific information about this "general" process can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

The tricky step is getting the refresh token because once you have that stored in a secure location, you can do anything with simple httpRequests.

To get a refresh token, a user has to agree to give your project access to certain features. This is called `scopes` in Google language. You can do this in many different ways (according to Google):

> There are several ways to make this request, and they vary based on
>   the type of application you are building. For example, a JavaScript
>   application might request an access token using a browser redirect to
>   Google, while an application installed on a device that has no browser
>   uses web service requests.

The one thing they don't tell you is that, in your case, it doesn't matter what medium you use to get the `refresh_token` because you are only using one account. The Google Drive API isn't really designed to be used like a server. It is designed to be used by a developer that wants to store information on each of its user's accounts. Like if you had a picture app, you could have a feature that stores edited picture on someone's personal Google Drive account.

What you (and many others who have recently asked about) want to do is essentially use a Drive account as a server. That means that the medium through which you get your `refresh_token` does not have to be related to the medium in which you are using the Drive Account.

For example in my specific case, I wanted a way to store user pictures on a server for free for an android app. I am using this free service called Parse to act as my database server, but they give you very limited file storage in their free tier.

Because of this, I decided to try and figure out how to use Google drive accounts to expand my storage. I created a generic gmail account something like "hostingaccount@gmail.com" to be the host of the files (15g for free).

To get my `refresh_token`, I setup a php server to authenticate that one account. When someone goes to the page I setup, they are prompted to login and then grant access to my project to use their Google Drive account (Specific scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`). I then setup the script to print the refresh_token for that account on the screen. I copied that string an put it into my server when now I can easily send httpRequests to:

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token/` to get an access token and to:

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files` to upload files.

I link it at the top of this edit, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230977/using-google-drive-api-parse-to-store-files-on-a-single-drive-account/32276202) answer shows you how to get a refresh token using my php method. I never spent the time to try an figure out how to get a refresh token any other way, but if you read my whole long answer I think I mention that I believe that this can also be done with the Android Google Drive API.

I have tried to help so many people with this problem, maybe I should just start a blog and make a tutorial about it ;)