# Is it possible to have an App with G.Drive as storage backend?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I want to make an App that will use one Google Drive as Data Storage.

This [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) requires that the user should login and access their own Drive.

But, instead, i want my users to connect to my (developer) drive and access all the files and respective file url.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32349773/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to Google Drive using the Android API and a specific account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349773/how-to-connect-to-google-drive-using-the-android-api-and-a-specific-account)