# How to store and access images from Google Drive from my web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api

I am developing web based application using ASP.Net MVC 5.0, in my application there is functionality to save images and display in view profile page. so I am  created folder in root folder for images and accessing them when required. Now the problem is my server space is limited so I want to use Google Drive facility to save images and access them when I required.

can anyone tell me how to achieve this or post me API documentation.

Thanks in advance for grateful help.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Your question is to broad please try and Do some research. https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230977/using-google-drive-api-parse-to-store-files-on-a-single-drive-account/32276202#32276202 In this question I use parse as my server with limited resources. All you have to do is change the code out for your server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the google drive rest api
and more preciselly the file.insert method 
one option is to do the http call by yourself 
or use the google drive sdk, this page has an .Net exemple at the bottom
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

note that you'll need to handle the authorization.

Comment: "note that you'll need to handle the authorization" which is the hardest and least documented part of his question. I don't think this addresses the root of his question of using a single account to basically act like a server.